# Reset which mail notification icons appear on lockscreen

Tags: 7.5, notifications, lock-screen

I have five separate email accounts set up on my Windows Phone 7 device: Outlook, Hotmail, Yahoo and two personal domains. My understanding is the notification icons on the lockscreen are determined by the order accounts were added (Outlook is always there regardless, right?). I want my two personal domains to be the other two notifications on the lockscreen. How can I accomplish this? Do I have to remove the accounts altogether and re-add them? Do I do so in reverse order I want them to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the notifications I wanted by removing my four non-Outlook accounts from the phone, then re-added them starting with the two in order I wanted to show on the lockscreen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Phone Settings
2. Go to "Lockscreen"
3. Scroll down to "Choose apps to show quick status"
4. Choose the items you want, and in the order you want, right there.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but perhaps you missed my edit this is a WP7 device.

Comment: Ah, yes. Unfortunately, the WP7 OS doesn't give you that ability directly. The account delete and re-add is the workaround.

Comment: Right. The whole point of my question really was what order to re-add them. I was hoping to avoid having to remove and re-enter all of them (and I thought at some point I'd read you have to do it in reverse order of the order desired, but couldn't find it again), but unfortunately that wasn't the case.