# Turning off Outlook notification on Lock Screen

Tags: settings, notifications, 7.8

My girlfriend has a Windows 7.8 Nokia Lumia 710 with her work emails linked through an Outlook account. The problem is that she doesn't want to see her work emails, or how many she has waiting for her, until she actually goes into the Outlook account itself.

Unfortunately I can't see any way of turning off the notification on the lock screen that shows the number of unread messages. It's stressing her out that she can't look at her phone without it telling her she has 24 emails from clients waiting to be read.

How can I do this for her?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a direct way to turn off notifications on the lock screen for Outlook/Hotmail?

Unfortunately, no there isn't.

> Is there a workaround to accomplish what you are asking?

Yes, there are two possibilities:

1. Say for instance you had 5 email accounts set up on the phone. Your phone lock screen will show notifications only for the first three accounts that were set up (yes, the order in which they are set up matters). So, this option requires you to add 3 email accounts ahead of the desired Outlook work account- that way you would only receive notifications from those other 3 accounts on the lock screen.
2. Your second option is to consider turning off data/wifi. When these are turned off, your email inbox will not be synced and hence no new notifications would appear on the lock screen.

For your reference: [Reset which mail notification icons appear on lockscreen](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/reset-which-mail-notification-icons-appear-on-lockscreen)

Comment: According to the link you reference, Outlook is ALWAYS there, no matter what order it's installed in?

Comment: Are you referring to the question stating `Outlook is always there regardless, right?` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: From my experience, that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. I'll investigate further

Comment: Strangely, there are three accounts on the phone: Two hotmail and one Outlook. The Outlook was installed last and it is the ONLY one visible on the lock screen.

Comment: Are you able to remove Outlook, add another email account (in the third spot) and then add Outlook (fourth spot)? Then, you should no longer be seeing Outlook notifications. Also, what is your primary account? And are these accounts connected to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Could you make it so the "download new content" only happens manually? That way it will only check for new emails when you actually want to, thus it can't update the lock screen or live tile.